# capture keystoke throughout linux OS and block it

Tags: python, keylogger

I'd like to capture certain keystokes on Linux and block their actions. For example:

```
if keystroke.Key == 'a':
    block_key_action('a')
    do_my_stuff('a')
```

What is the simplest way to do it? I know about pykeylogger module, but I do not know how to block key action.

Did the same thing on Windows via Autohotkey, but it seems there is not viable equivalent on Linux yet.

Comment: You are essentially asking us how to write malware. Tread carefully.

Comment: @JaredSmith, did the same thing on Windows via Autohotkey. The is no need for malware to block key action.

Comment: You are thinking of solving your immediate problem and your own pure intentions. But this is an *open forum on the internet*. People looking to write malware could use answers to this question as a resource to do so. And windows has an entirely different security model, so I fail to see how that's relevant.

Comment: @JaredSmith omg, do you want me to convince you about something or you just trolling me? I don't have time for this, dude.

Comment: I'm not trolling you. A keylogger is malware that captures system-wide keystrokes. You are asking us how to write one in Python. That is against the rules of StackOverflow, and this question should be closed.

Comment: @JaredSmith, keylogger is a keylogger and nothing more. There are a ton of questions about them on StackOverflow. Just google around. If want to submit a complaint just do it.